# Hitting OIDC endpoint /.well-known/openid-configuration from outside cluster results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault, kops, kubernetes-apiserver

Using kOps to deploy a kubernetes cluster to AWS, I'm trying to configure an external Hashicorp Vault to use JWT/OIDC auth.  Following the tutorial at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/jwt/oidc_providers#kubernetes, from the vault, I try to issue:

```
vault write auth/jwt/config oidc_discovery_url="${ISSUER}" oidc_discovery_ca_pem=@ca.crt
```

But it comes back with a 401/Unauthorized.  Prior to this on the kubernetes cluster I did:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding oidc-reviewer --clusterrole=system:service-account-issuer-discovery --group=system:unauthenticated
```

To supposedly ensure that the OIDC discovery URLs do not require authentication.

From the external vault machine, I simply try to:

```
curl --cacert ca.crt $ISSUER/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

And I also get a 401/Unauthorized.  It is reaching the server OK so it's not a cert issue or anything, just something to do with the kubernetes/API configuration.

Additionally I changed the kOps deployment to supposedly AlwaysAllow API calls with:

```
apiVersion: kops.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind:Cluster
spec:
  api:
    dns: { }
  authorization:
    alwaysAllow: { }
```

But this didn't make any differene.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could be missing?

I can otherwise create a kubectl proxy and hit the endpoint from there just fine.

Comment: Is Vault running in Kubernetes or not?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin Vault is not in the Kubernetes cluster.  It's running externally.  It's more of a Kubernetes question, why I can't openly hit the openid-configuration.  Or can I only ever hit it without authentication through the kubectl proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enable OIDC discovery from kOps. This puts the OIDC discovery files in S3 rather than serving them from an authenticated endpoint on the APIServer:

```
spec:
  serviceAccountIssuerDiscovery:
    discoveryStore: s3://publicly-readable-store
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to be able to get this quickly. Looks like you have kubectl access so you can use a raw request to get the openid-config

```
kubectl get --raw=/.well-known/openid-configuration
```